# onClick event is undifned

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks, onclick, use-state

So I am building an appointment app where if someone is sick i need to change the color of that person to red.
I am working with useState for this. My problem is that when i want to change that person my event handler doesnt target the person i want to. Can someone help me with that please?

this is my code

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {clients} from "./utils"
import  "./userlist.css"

const AddClient = ({addContact}) => {
    const [client, setClient] = useState(clients)
   
    const onChangeClient = (e) =>{
            setClient({...client, [e.target.name] : e.target.value})
    }
   
    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault();
            addContact(client);
            setClient({first_name: client.first_name, 
                        last_name: client.last_name, 
                        phone: client.phone, 
                        email: client.email
                     });}

    const isSick = client.isSick

    const handleSick = () =>{
        setClient(client => ({ ...client, [isSick]: !client[isSick]})
        )
        console.log('working')
        
        setClient(prevState => {
            console.log("prevState",prevState)
            return prevState
        })
            }

    
    

   return (
   <div>
       
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   
           <input 
           type="text"
           value = {client.first_name}
           placeholder="name"
           name = "first_name"
           onChange={onChangeClient}/>
           
           <input 
           type="text"
           value = {client.last_name}
           name="last_name"
           placeholder="surname"
           onChange={onChangeClient}/>
       
           <input 
           type="email"
           value = {client.email}
           name="email"
           placeholder="email"
           onChange={onChangeClient}/>
   
           <input 
           type="number"
           value = {client.number}
           name="phone"
           placeholder="phone"
           onChange={onChangeClient}/>
           
           <button >Add Client</button>
           </form>
           <tbody  className="tablerow">
            {clients.map((client) => (
                <tr className="table-row" style={{backgroundColor: isSick && 'red'}} key={client.phone}>
                    <td className=" col col-1">{client.first_name}</td>
                    <td className=" col col-2">{client.last_name}</td>
                    <td className=" col col-3">{client.email}</td>
                    <td className=" col col-4">{client.phone}</td>
                    <td><button key={client.phone} onClick={() => handleSick()}>Sick</button></td>
                </tr> )
                )}
        </tbody>
           
   </div>
   )}
   
   
   export default AddClient
```

[this is what i see on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B50fH.png)

Comment: You're not getting desired result because your not passing the client to the handleSick method. You should either pass the index or pass the client to to the method: `handleSick(client)`. I'm also very confused about what this is doing in your code:  `const isSick = client.isSick`

Comment: Hi Kevin even if i pass the client it's not working. I am defining isSick so i can use it in my fuction @KevinZ

Answer (score 0):

Check this working implementation of what you are trying to do: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-avueyp?file=src%2FApp.js

- Consider that we are using a static array of objects as our data model ( clients ), usually you would use data retrieved by a database, so every update to any of that data will have to be written on the db and updated data has to be sent back to th client. React UI will only care to render that updated data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @CesarePalonara, for me it seems not to be working i updated my editClient function. In the console it changes the state but it doesnt change the background demo like in your code

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, try to analyze the code and understand how I'm handling the updates.  All updates in React must be immutable, so if you are updating an object/ array, you must return a new object/array in order to trigger a re-render.

Comment: Allright i will check it again

Comment: So lets say i have a couple of data base. 1 is clients 2 is Doctors 3 is Assistants. can i still use the same code?

Comment: If you understand code logic, sure, you'll just have to make some slight changes probably...

Comment: i have a question why did you use useContext? Sorry for al the questions :$